# How to resize QScrollArea when a scrollbar appears (so only one bar is necessary)?

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I have a splitview, and on the left-hand side a number of buttons. I'm putting them into a scrollbar so that they don't get squished when the container layout gets too short; but the only two options I seem to have are:

1: QScrollArea does not resize the view, so that when the window gets too short, the vertical scrollbar causes the buttons to be blocked (side-to-side) and the horizontal scrollbar also appears.

2: QScrollArea tries to resize the widget it contains (using `setWidgetResizable(true)`), but fits it within the same smaller size, which causes some of the text on the buttons to get clipped off the sides.

[image: Example of both behaviors that I don't want.]

What I want is for the QScrollArea to maintain the default size of the widget (horizontally) and expand ITSELF by the size of a scrollbar when it deems one to be necessary (vertically). There's plenty of space to the right in this split view, and I would prefer if the scroll area got wider and expanded the left-hand side instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation, which was solved by overriding QScrollArea::sizeHint() in the descendant.

```hpp
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QScrollArea>

class MyScrollArea : public QScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QSize sizeHint() const override
    {
        auto newSize = QScrollArea::sizeHint();
        newSize.setWidth(newSize.width()
                         + verticalScrollBar()->sizeHint().width());
        return newSize;
    }
};
```